# Кнопка внизу recyclerview

Tags: android

Подскажите как прикрутить кнпоку внизу recyclerview, чтобы она оставалась, а все что выше скроллилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    ...
    android:orientation="vertical" />
        <RecyclerView
            ... 
            android:layout_weight="1"/> //позволяет развернуть список на всю незанятую высоту
        <Button
            ... />
</LinearLayout>
```